# How to modify the "dm-*" value?

Tags: linux, multipath, device-mapper

As I command multipath -ll, the output show like this.

```
ocr3 (149455400000000000000000001000000ca0200000d000000) dm-9 IET,VIRTUAL-DISK
[size=980M][features=0][hwhandler=0]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=0][active]
 \_ 1:0:0:11 sdo 8:224 [active][ready]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=0][enabled]
 \_ 1:0:0:10 sdn 8:208 [active][ready]
```

However, I want to modify the dm-9 to dm-1.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `/dev/dm-1` device-mapper device currently in use by some other mapping, or is it free?

Run `dmsetup ls -o blkdevname` to check.

If dm-1 is currently the first unassigned `dm-<n>` number, and your `/dev/mapper/ocr3` is not currently in use by anything, you could try:

```
multipath -f ocr3
multipath -v2
```

to free and then re-scan the `ocr3` multipath map, in the hope that it will snatch the free dm-1 device for itself. But this is uncertain and will not persist over a reboot.

In general, you should not assume that the `dm-<n>` names will stay the same from one boot to the next. They are assigned in order to any disk mappings that are achieved using the device-mapper subsystem:

- LVM logical volumes
- dm-multipath devices
- encrypted devices (`cryptsetup`)
- some software RAID configurations (`dmraid`)

The `dm-<n>` names are for the device-mapper tools themselves to use: you, as the system administrator, should not use them directly. They are the machine-friendly names; you should use the corresponding human-friendly names instead, like `/dev/mapper/ocr3` in this case.